# Google Sheet Query Filtering doesnt seem to work numeric values

Tags: google-sheets-query

`=IF(E3="Met notificatie";QUERY(CSVupload!A2:I;"select F, D, E, C, B where A = '"&C3&"' AND I>=0 " );IF(E3="Zonder notificatie";QUERY(CSVupload!A2:I;"select F, D, E, C, B where A = '"&C3&"' AND I contains '0' " );QUERY(CSVupload!A2:I;"select F, D, E, C, B where A = '"&C3&"' ")))`

(I'm using the Dutch version so some words are different... when having an answer please just use your own language settings; I'll find out how that differs.)

E3 contains 3 types ("met notificatie", "zonder notificatie", "alle") of text and it needs to filter all cells from the second tab(CSVupload!A2:I) only the result now is that with this formula the results of "Met notificatie" and "Alle" are the same. Can someone explain why those two don't seem different?

Comment: Got it! =IF(REGEXMATCH(E3;"Met") ;QUERY(CSVupload!A2:I;"select F, D, E, C, B where A = '"&C3&"' AND I>= 1 " );IF(E3="Zonder notificatie";QUERY(CSVupload!A2:I;"select F, D, E, C, B where A = '"&C3&"' AND I contains '0' " );QUERY(CSVupload!A2:I;"select F, D, E, C, B where A = '"&C3&"' ")))

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
=IFS(
E3="Met notificatie",QUERY(CSVupload!A2:I,"select F, D, E, C, B where A = '"&C3&"' AND I>=0 " ),
E3="Zonder notificatie",QUERY(CSVupload!A2:I,"select F, D, E, C, B where A = '"&C3&"' AND I contains '0' " ),
E3="Alle",QUERY(CSVupload!A2:I,"select F, D, E, C, B where A = '"&C3&"' ")
)
```

Comment: Thnx for the shot. Now im getting a #N/A (No value) ...